# Python Quantlib : How to value the Non Deliverable currency Interest Rate Swaps?

Tags: programming, derivatives, swaps, quantlib

I followed all the procedure in Quantlib to process interest rate swap valuation through Python Quantlib. I valued more than a million records. All the valuation is almost the expected amount. But 'Interest rate Swap' of these currencies ( CNY, KRW, THB, TWD) are way off than the expected valuation. Almost 100% variation in amount has been observed from the reported value.

Any suggestion on above currencies why their valuation are so different ?
I read all the theories on Non Deliverable Swap currencies but I want to implement something in Quantlib to get the correct valuation. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quantlib supports only IRS. But you're trying to find NDS valuation.

IRS valuation:

PV (*present value*) of the interest payments on the **fixed leg**:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \delta({T}_{j-1},{T}_{j}) \cdot K \cdot P(0, T_j) 
\end{equation}
PV (*present value*) of the interest payments on the **floating leg**:

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \delta({T}_{j-1},{T}_{j}) \cdot F({T}_{j-1},{T}_{j}) \cdot P(0, T_j) 
\end{equation}
where:

$\delta({T}_{j-1},{T}_{j})$ - day-count fraction

$K$ , $F({T}_{j-1},{T}_{j}$ - fixed and forward rates

$P(0, T_j)$ - discount factor (price of zero coupon bonds)

For NDS (non-deliverable swap) formula:

\begin{equation}
F(0,T) - S_0 = S_0 \bigg(\frac {1 + r_d \cdot T}{1 + r_f \cdot T} - 1 \bigg) = \\
= \frac {S_0(r_d - r_f) \cdot T}{1 + r_f \cdot T} \approx S_0(r_d - r_f) \cdot T
\end{equation}

But for NDS(floating for floating, fixed for floating) are usually used in emerging markets where the currency is illiquid, subject to exchange restrictions, or even non-convertible the quanto correction must be apply to foreign currency forward rates. For instance, if you want to evaluate cross currency swap the effective forward rate used in pricing:

\begin{equation}
f = (0, t_j, t_{j+1}) \cdot (1 + \rho_j \cdot \sigma_{f_j} \cdot \sigma_{FX} \cdot t_j)
\end{equation}

where

$\rho_j$ - FX/Forward rate correlation

$\sigma_{FX}$ - forex rate volatility

More information: Boenkost, Schmidt *"Notes on convexity and quanto adjustments
for interest rates and related options"* (2003), SSRN 1375570

Comment: Do you have any link document or example to solve this one ?

Comment: @Rahul,  Sure: [VALUATION AND HEDGING OF DIFFERENTIAL SWAPS] (http://140.113.26.31/uploads/journal_paper_file/journal_file/5425407674700065f6d30400/250_bd6ee70e.pdf) [Interest rate swap : quanto LIBOR and CMS rate](https://lbezone.ust.hk/pdfviewer/web/viewer.html?file=aHR0cHM6Ly9sYmV6b25lLnVzdC5oay9vYmovMS9vL2I5OTEzNzIvYjk5MTM3Mi5wZGY=#page=1)

Comment: Old thread, but can anyone comment how the quanto adjustment is carried out in practice. E.g. I have market quoted NDIRS (fix vs. compounded 7d Repo) in CNY. How would I bootstrap the curve and what's the result even? CNY forward rates that need to be quanto adjusted? or quanto-adjusted ones already? in case of the former, how would I adjust my CNY (USD) cashflows that I project off this curve?